# Syncing Contacts from iPhone to Outlook

Tags: iphone, email, ms-office, contacts, exchange-activesync

I'd like to sync my iPhone's contacts to Outlook. The account is linked, so my email is updating, but it won't sync the contacts.

How do I do it?

Comment: Are the contacts ones that you created on the iPhone and stored in another account, or are they ones that are currently in Outlook that you want to have on your iPhone?  

If it's the latter, you have this flagged with "exchange-activesync", so I presume that you have this account set up on your iPhone as an Exchange account.  If so, in your iPhone settings (Settings -> Mail, Contacts, ... -> your account), check to make sure that you have sync of each of the individual items selected.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exact guide offered by copytrans (mentioned in the previous answer) which shows how to transfer iphone contacts to Outlook on a PC: http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-iphone-contacts-to-outlook/

Answer (score -1):

> To [sync contacts with your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1296), choose "Sync Contacts with" within iTunes for Windows, or "Sync Address Book Contacts" on your Mac.
>
> You can sync your contacts with:
>
> Microsoft Outlook 2003, Microsoft Outlook 2007, Microsoft Outlook 2010 (Windows XP, Windows Vista, or Windows 7)
>   Windows Address Book (Windows XP)
>   Windows Contacts (Windows Vista / Windows 7)
>   Address Book (Mac OS X)
>   Microsoft Entourage 2004, Microsoft Entourage 2008, or Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac
>
> Note: If using Microsoft Entourage, use Microsoft Entourage 2008 12.1.2 or later if syncing with Mac OS X v10.6 or later. If you would like to sync data on your Mac with Entourage, enable syncing between Entourage and Address Book.
>   Notes:
>
> When syncing contacts, you can choose to sync all of your contacts or only selected groups. The option to sync selected items may not show up until after the first sync.
>   You can select a group of contacts to which all new contacts created on your iOS device will be added.
>
> Additional options for syncing include syncing your contacts with Yahoo or Gmail/Google Mail. You will need to configure it with the user name and password for your Yahoo or Google account.

If you want to import contacts without using iTunes, try using a third party tool to do so. We've used [CopyTrans Contacts](http://www.copytrans.net/copytranscontacts.php) to do this.

Here is a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0YPmMLeajU&feature=youtu.be) to a video showing the process.

Comment: Is there someone I can actually call for more help?

Comment: Why exactly was this modded down?